# sencha touch :Trying to add a null item as a child of Container with itemId/id: ext-comp-1050

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha Touch. I have an existing web application I have to improve.

I created a new panel and try to add items to an existing panel but I get an error when trying to add a NULL element as a child of Container itemId/id: ext-comp-1050

My code is as follows

```
Myapp.views.mainView = new Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
   initComponent: function() {
      this.items = [
          Myapp.views.welcomePanel, // new panel I am trying to add
          Myapp.views.settingsView,
          Myapp.views.placePopup,
          Myapp.views.newsPanel
      ];
      this.dockedItems = [];
      this.cardAnimation='slide';
      this.html = null;
      this.fullscreen = true;
      this.layout = 'card';
      this.align = 'stretch';
      Myapp.views.mainView.superclass.initComponent.call(this); 
  }
});
```

and the code of welcome Panel is

```
Myapp.views.welcomePanel = new Ext.Panel({
    frame:true,
    autoHeight:true,
    collapsible:true,
    layout:'card',
    items:[
       Myapp.views.mapPlaces,
       Myapp.views.listOfPlaces
    ],
    dockedItems:[
       Myapp.views.mainToolBar,
       Myapp.views.changerPanelsToolbar
    ]
});
```

`Myapp.views.mapPlaces, Myapp.views.listOfPlaces, Myapp.views.mainToolBar, Myapp.views.changerPanelsToolbar`

are pre-existing & working without problem

Please help